# Haskell type error `map (\idx -> (2.400 ** idx) / fact idx) [0..9]` `fact :: Int -> Int`, Expected Int, Actual Double

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, typeerror

While working on this problem below, I am getting a strange error.

[image: Problem Statement]

```hs
module Main where

fact :: Int -> Int
fact 0 = 1
fact n = foldr (*) 1 [1..n]

calc_e_to_power :: Double -> Double
calc_e_to_power x = foldr (+) 0 $ map (\idx -> (x ** idx) / fact idx) [0..9]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ calc_e_to_power 2.4000
```

I am getting type error for `fact` function which says expected `Int`, got `Double`. How can the type of `idx` be Double here.

I am aware that `**` will convert the type of first expression of division to Double, but `2.3243 / 3` works perfectly fine in ghci. When I remove the type signature of `fact`, it complies and works perfectly.

Not really sure what am I missing here.

[image: Error]

I have also recreated the example in Repl. Can someone help me understand what's wrong here ?

Link to Code on repl https://replit.com/@VipulSharma12/HeavyGrandioseCrypto#src/Main.hs

Comment: Your `fact idx` will return an `Int`, and you can only use `/` if both operands have the same type and are a member of the `Fractional` typeclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your expression:

```
map (\idx -> (x ** idx) / fact idx) [0..9]
```

`fact` expects an `Int` and returns an `Int`, so `idx` should be an `Int` and `fact idx` is also an `Int`. But this clashes with the fact that `(**)` is defined as [**`(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42--42-) takes two items of the same type that should be members of the `Floating` typeclass.

Especially since the type of `x` is `Double`, and thus `x ** idx` will be a `Double` as well, this requires `idx` to be a `Double`. But `idx` should be an `Int` for the `fact idx`, and an item can not be an `Int` and `Double` at the same time.

What we can do is work with [**`(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:-94-) which accepts as second operand an item of type `b` such that `b` is a member of the `Integral` typeclass, which is the case when `b` is an `Int`.

Now the numerator `x ^ idx` will have type `Double` (since `(^)` has type `(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a` whereas `fact idx` has type `Int`. We can not divide a `Double` by an `Int`, since [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42--42-) requires both operands to have the same type, and that type should be a member of the `Fractional` typeclass (and an `Int` is *not* a member of this typeclass).

We can work with [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert an `Integral` number (`Int` is a member of the `Integral` typeclass), to any type `b` where `b` is a member of the `Num` typeclass (and `Double` is a member of this typeclass).

We thus can fix the expression and rewrite this to:

```
calc_e_to_power :: Double -> Double
calc_e_to_power x = foldr (+) 0 $ map (\idx -> (x ^ idx) / fromIntegral (fact idx)) [0..9]
```

We can work with [**`sum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) to avoid writing that part with `foldr`:

```
calc_e_to_power :: Double -> Double
calc_e_to_power x = sum (map (\idx -> (x ^ idx) / fromIntegral (fact idx)) [0..9])
```

Comment: Efficiency note: the truncated serie is ultimately a polynomial function, so we can eliminate all these costly floating-point divisions by using the usual [Horner's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) for polynomial evaluation.

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes so much sense now. I totally missed while `2.321 / 2` works in ghci, they are of type Num and not Int.

Need to learn about various types and there hierarchy in detail now