# Can Someone explain this Haskell problem?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm a beginner in Haskell. I tried a program in Hackerrank.

```
The series expansion of e^x is given by:

 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3!...

Evaluate e^x for given values of x by using the above expansion for the first 10 terms.
```

The Input is of type Double ex: 20.0000

I wrote the program which is

```
exCalcFn num 2 = num ** 2 / 2
exCalcFn num n = exCalcFn num (n-1) + ((num ** n) / (product[1..n]))
```

I will add 1 and the number itself at main function.

But the problem here is when I give type signature

```
exCalcFn :: Double -> Int -> Double
```

the code is not working. But When I'm not giving the type signature, code works!.
Can someone Explain me why please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get an error message? What is it?

Comment: `num ** n` is likely to give a type error because n is an Int. Try ^ instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell type error `map (\idx -> (2.400 ** idx) / fact idx) [0..9]` `fact :: Int -> Int`, Expected Int, Actual Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68671180/haskell-type-error-map-idx-2-400-idx-fact-idx-0-9-fact-int)?

Comment: @Bergi - yes, definitely similar to [question 68671180](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68671180/haskell-type-error-map-idx-2-400-idx-fact-idx-0-9-fact-int). But I prefer to put the Horner rule thing in the newest incarnation of the question.

Answer (score 4):

In the body of your function, you are using operator `**`. This Fortran-ish operator needs both operands to be of *floating* type, but from the type signature, your exponent is an `Int` quantity. Hence the problem.

Testing under the `ghci` interpreter:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :type (**)
 (**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
 λ> 
 λ> :type (^)
 (^) :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a
 λ>
```

Fortunately, the language provides operator `^` to raise a number to some integer power. More details here:
[Haskell numeric types](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html)

Also, as n is an integer, so is expression `product [1..n]`. But operator `/` is solely for fractional types, while the language provides `div` and `divMod` for integer division:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :type (/)
 (/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
 λ>
```

So you need to insert the `fromIntegral` polymorphic converter to allow the compiler to convert your integer product into the same fractional type as the numerator.

Overall, we get:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :{
|λ> exCalcFn :: Double -> Int -> Double
|λ> exCalcFn num 2 = (num ^ 2) / 2
|λ> exCalcFn num n = exCalcFn num (n-1) + ((num ^ n) / (fromIntegral (product [1..n])))
|λ> :}
 λ>
```

**Sanity check:**

```
 λ> 
 λ> let x = 1  in  (1 + x + exCalcFn x 20)
 2.718281828459045
 λ> 
 λ> y = let x = 0.5  in  (1 + x + exCalcFn x 20)
 λ> y*y
 2.7182818284590455
 λ>
```

### Efficiency note:

The above code does typecheck, but it is seriously suboptimal. The proper way to evaluate a polynomial function, in any programming language, is known as the [Horner rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method). For a polynomial function of degree n, it costs only n additions and n multiplications.

The Horner rule consists essentially in rearranging,
say:

a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>*x<sup>1</sup> + a<sub>2</sub>*x<sup>2</sup> + a<sub>3</sub>*x<sup>3</sup> + a<sub>4</sub>*x<sup>4</sup>

into:

a<sub>0</sub> + x*(a<sub>1</sub> + x*(a<sub>2</sub> + x*(a<sub>3</sub> + x*a<sub>4</sub>)))

In Haskell, the Horner rule happens to be a nice fit for library function [`foldr1 :: Foldable fd => (a -> a -> a) -> fd a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldr1):

```
hornerEval :: [Double] -> Double -> Double
hornerEval cs x = foldr1 (\c acc -> acc*x + c)  cs
```

Regarding the case of the first 10 terms of the Taylor/Maclaurin expansion of e<sup>x</sup>, the coefficients can be computed like this:

```
factorials :: [Integer]
factorials = unfoldr  (\(k,prod) -> Just (prod, (k+1,k*prod)))  (1,1)

revFactorials :: Int -> [Double]
revFactorials n = take (n+1) $ map  (\k -> 1.0 / (fromIntegral k))  factorials

expCoeffs :: [Double]
expCoeffs = revFactorials 10
```

And so:

```
 λ> 
 λ> approxExp x = hornerEval expCoeffs x
 λ>
```

**Sanity check #2:**

```
 λ> 
 λ> approxExp 1.0
 2.7182818011463845
 λ> 
 λ> let y = approxExp 0.5 in y*y
 2.718281828416961
 λ>
```

Comment: Thanks man! Upto sanity check I can understand what you are saying. But after that everything becomes Greek and latin

Comment: @KARTHICKUMARK I have added a bit more details about the Horner rule. Hope that helps. But you still have to go thru the relevant Wikipedia page for a full exposition.